# How can we hide icon from Drawer / Launcher / Application Manager programatically in android

Tags: android

Can any one Help me out "How can we hide or unhide application icon everywhere from phone by any other utility application"

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This will remove launcher icon from drawer, not applicable for application manager.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is not possible, for security reasons you cannot hide the app from the app listings.  The best you can do is to give your app an obscure name or put something like "preferences" behind its title.

Comment: but there is a app "LauncherPro" in that we can hide launcher app....so it means it is possible.\

Comment: They can't hide it from the list of apps in the install list, only the launcher.  If they can, please tell, because this is a security bug, and should be filed with the Android open source project...

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
<intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

from the manifest, so your app won't be listed in the launcher anymore ;)

Hiding it completely from the appListing in the deeps of the settings shouldn't be possible afaik.

Comment: i want it programatically.....there is one button like toggle by which one can hide/unhide app launcher icon from the drawer

Comment: That may not be possible, cause in this cause you would register and unregister over and over again from the launcher. What I posted is the only solution for a purpose like that. =/

Comment: if we do as you said....then how can we launche our home activity?? and there is one application "LauncherPro" in that we can hide launch icon..that means this is possible in android.

Comment: Using intents or other stuff you register in your intent filter. Maybe this way you app could be launched directly from the market only... or sth...

Comment: But there is one application "LauncherPro" in that we can hide/unhide launch icon..that means this is possible in android

Comment: Who knows what lowLevel shit they have done :p (-> loves the app ^^) ... maybe they achieved it, but that's kinda secret