# Hide android app icon from home menu from another android app

Tags: android

How can I hide some other app icon from Main Menu where all the installed apps are displayed on the device. I want to hide one app from another app.
I know the package name of the app which I wanna hide, but when I want to open the hidden app from my app, it should open.

Can anyone give me some code sample, to hide android app if we know the package name?

Comment: Assuming you own both apps and are not trying to hide a competitor app, why wouldn't you make just one app instead of two?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, since the behaviour you describe seems like a virus. Avoiding people using another App (in other words, hiding it) it's like uninstalling it, which should not be admissible.

Applications in the main menu are only showed if the developer has specified in the AndroidManifest.xml the next lines for the main Activity:

```
<activity android:name="Name"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Maybe on rooted devices you can research in this way, **but i do not recommend you since it is probably ilegal**.

Comment: I've Air for Android game developed in Flash Professional using Action-script; As you mentioned above I removed `<intent-filter>` tag from the manifest, now I'm getting error while installing the app. The error is `Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that (I don't consider rooted devices or custom ROMs) because it would be a serious security problem if, as a developer, you could decide to hide other developer app icons.

Moreover, likely any app in the store (maybe with few exception) has the following lines in the manifest file for the "main" activity:

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

That indicates to system to show the app icon in the launcher.

If you need to do that for one of your apps, please refer to this question: [How can we hide icon from Drawer / Launcher / Application Manager programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934309/how-can-we-hide-icon-from-drawer-launcher-application-manager-programaticall)

Comment: but there are some apps in google play which help us to hide app icon.

Comment: I've Air for Android game developed in Flash Professional using Action-script; As you mentioned above I removed `<intent-filter>` tag from the manifest, now I'm getting error while installing the app. The error is `Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package`

Comment: You need to create a specific question for that problem because it's different or at least paste here your manifest file and the logcat so we can help you. Thanks.