# how to hide app's icon correctly?

Tags: android

similar questions have been asked earlier, but the requirement was to hide the app's icon from drawer completely, by removing these two lines-

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
```

However, my case is a bit complicated. i want to hide my app in the drawer and launch it from other apps. if i remove those two lines, i wont be able to launch my app. for example launching a module from xposed framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically

Comment: thanks for the comment, but i want my app to be hidden by default forever.

Comment: just hide it and never call back it will be hidden forever

Comment: but i would need to launch the app for hiding it, i want it to be installed hidden

Comment: ok..by this once the app icon will be launched after that it will be hidden

Comment: refer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934309/how-can-we-hide-icon-from-drawer-launcher-application-manager-programaticall>

Comment: Look up "open intent" in the Android developer guides. Basically, you'll have to remove the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER category and open your app through an open intent (or through an http broadcast receiver).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk du bist boss! :) this answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Download source code from here([Hide and Unhide the app icon in android programmatically](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2017/06/hide-and-unhide-app-icon-in-android.html))

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.deepshikha.hideappicon;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn_hide;
    private static final ComponentName LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME = new ComponentName(
            "com.deepshikha.hideappicon", "com.deepshikha.hideappicon.Launcher");

    public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    boolean boolean_permission;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        fn_permission();
        listener();
    }

    private void init() {
        btn_hide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_hide);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");


        if (isLauncherIconVisible()) {
            btn_hide.setText("Hide");
        } else {
            btn_hide.setText("Unhide");
        }


    }

    private void listener() {
        btn_hide.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_hide:

                progressDialog.show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (isLauncherIconVisible()) {
                            btn_hide.setText("Hide");
                        } else {
                            btn_hide.setText("Unhide");
                        }
                    }
                }, 10000);


                if (boolean_permission) {

                    if (isLauncherIconVisible()) {
                        fn_hideicon();
                    } else {
                        fn_unhide();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

        }

    }

    private boolean isLauncherIconVisible() {
        int enabledSetting = getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME);
        return enabledSetting != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    }

    private void fn_hideicon() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Important!");
        builder.setMessage("To launch the app again, dial phone number 1234567890");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            }
        });
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder.show();
    }

    private void fn_unhide() {
        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.deepshikha.hideappicon.MainActivity.class);
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    private void fn_permission() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }
        } else {
            boolean_permission = true;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                boolean_permission = true;


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LaunchAppReceiver.java:**

```
package com.deepshikha.hideappicon;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

/**
 * Created by deepshikha on 9/6/17.
 */

public class LaunchAppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String LAUNCHER_NUMBER = "1234567890";
    private static final ComponentName LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME = new ComponentName(
            "com.deepshikha.hideappicon", "com.deepshikha.hideappicon.Launcher");

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if (LAUNCHER_NUMBER.equals(phoneNubmer)) {
            setResultData(null);

            if (isLauncherIconVisible(context)) {

            } else {
                Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(appIntent);
            }


        }

    }

    private boolean isLauncherIconVisible(Context context) {
        int enabledSetting = context.getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME);
        return enabledSetting != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Have you tried this,

Comment: thanks for the answer :) but i want my app to be installed hidden and i should still be able to launch it from other apps.

Comment: So, you need to hide the installation..??

Comment: do you understand English? :)

Comment: ha haa.. I just wondered what you asked, well for security reasons you cannot hide them, for sure..

Comment: i am sure i can hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Don't remove

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: i solved it with the help of Stephan Branczyk's comment.